# Spring bean java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, websphere

I am getting below error, I believe its due to OLDER version of spring-beans.jar, In my LIB i have spring-beans--3.1.1.RELEASE.jar but still getting below error. I have deployed my application on WAS 8.5.X server.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;
```

Is there any way to search on linux to find the culprit jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what jar file that class is loaded from, adding the line below to your Java program

```
System.out.println(System.class.getResource(
           "/org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.class"));
```

which should print something like

```
jar:file:/C:/my-program/lib/spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.class
```

or using Guava's `Resources.getResource("org/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues.class");`

---

`NoSuchMethodError` error usually means there is a mismatch between the version of that class and the version expected by its clients. It could eventually be the case that the spring-beans jar version is actually correct- if that is the case, it is worth checking the version of the code invoking it, too.

Comment: For WebSphere traditional, if you want to avoid app recompilation/redeployment, I'd suggest enabling the "Verbose class loading" option in the administrative console, on the JVM configuration panel, which adds `-verbose:class` to the Java invocation. It will print out the source of every class load by the JVM to native_stderr.log, which you can search for the classes in question.

Comment: Or manually copy a JSP out to the installed directory, with scriptlet running the same kind of code. I was using a WebSphere-specific mechanism here, but I'll have to see if this generic one works just as well: https://dougbreaux.github.io/2010/07/29/finding-a-java-class-in-your-servlet-container.html